# Google CDN Url for the Full featured CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have downloaded CKEditor 4.3.2 from ckeditor site but i need to store lot files like more than 100 in my project which is bad. I searched for the 'cdn url of ckeditor' and got the url for the ckeditor standard package. I can use that but it does not have all the features which i need.
Please provide me the url for the ckeditor full ferature.

Atleast could any body tell me 'URL' is there for ckeditor full feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have seen http://cdnjs.com/libraries/ckeditor/ also but it gives us only Standard ckeditor not full featured.

Comment: Official CDN will be announced soon. You can follow this [ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9921).